# Toastr - issue with the options

Tags: javascript, toast

I called a toastr message via

```js
Command: toastr["success"]("foo")

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "2000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
```

It seems the options have no effect, the `timeOut`and the `positionClass` were not overridden.

May somebody give me a info whats wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to slightly rename your question? It comes up as the second google result searching for "toastr options" without any indication this link is about an issue with toastr options. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change options before the first call of toastr's methods (info, success, etc.)

Comment: Do you have to set options each time you want to change the style of a message? or can i pass a config object to my toastr call functions?

Answer (score 0):

you should change your jquery version if 1.2.3 is the version you use, i built a jsbin and tested it. Just try it with a newer version for e.g "1.9.1". if you need to stick to 1.2.3 try another version of toastr compatible with jquery 1.2.3.

here is the jsbin: 
https://jsbin.com/rufuganane/edit?html,output

Comment: Its not the reason - nethertheless tx to you

Comment: did you check the jsbin ?

Comment: Yes, I´ve changed to 1.9.1

Comment: did you noticed the options is set before success invocation?

Comment: Yes, now I noticed it. That was the problem.